# Como atualizar somente uma propriedade de um objeto utilizando OutputCache na ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, visual-studio-2015, model

Olá, pessoal.

Estou com um problema que nem sei se tem uma solução desse jeito.

Tenho uma ActionResult que retorna o conteúdo de um gráfico em Jquery.

O resultado desse gráfico precisará sempre estar guardado num cache pra página não ficar pesada.

Só que uma propriedade desse model que precisa retornar true ou false dependendo se o usuário está logado ou não.

Pra ele atualizar corretamente eu precisaria retirar SOMENTE ESSA PROPRIEDADE do cache

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByCustom ="none")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    GraficosModel model = geradorGraficos.GerarGrafico();

    if (this.UsuarioPesquisa != null)
    {
        model.usuarioLogado = true;               
    }
    else
    {
        model.usuarioLogado = false;
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Essa propriedade 'model.usuarioLogado' teria que estar fora do cache. Existe alguma forma de fazer isso? Pois sempre está trazendo falso.

Comment: por que você deve colocar o usuário Logado em um objeto? a Session não resolveria?

Comment: a forma como foi feita a aplicação assim já está desse jeito

Answer (score 0):

Rafaela,
como essa propriedade está dentro da resposta, todo o conteúdo estará no cache.

Tenta alterar esse trecho do seus código:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByCustom ="none")]
```

Para:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByCustom ="UsuarioLogado")]
```

e depois altere seu Global.asax para:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg) 
{
    return arg.ToLower() == "UsuarioLogado" ? User.Identity.Name : string.Empty;
}
```

Com esse parâmetro personalizado para o atributo OutputCache, podemos ter uma página em cache quando não houver nenhum usuário autenticado e uma página armazenada em cache pelo Usuário.